# On lower/upper bounds for Dedekind sum

Tags: nt.number-theory

The Dedekind sum [$s(p,q)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_sum) can be both positive and negative. What are the known lower/upper bounds in terms of p,q?  (I would prefer something that grows not faster than q)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a fixed $q$, the maximum is $$s(1,q)=-{1\over4}+{1\over6q}+{q\over12}$$ and the minimum is $s(q-1,q)=-s(1,q)$.

Comment: Wow, that's great. And 1/12 is especially delightful. Thanks! Can you also give a reference, what to cite?

Comment: This follows from a finite-Fourier-series version of Cauchy-Schwartz. The earliest reference I'm aware of is H. Rademacher, Zur Theorie der Dedekindschen Summen, Math. Z. 63 (1956) 445-463. With some work, one can obtain even better bounds (see, e.g., <a href="http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/math.NT/0305421">my paper with S. Robins and S. Zacks</a>).

Comment: $s(p,q)=q^{-2}\sum af(a)$ plus terms not relevant here, where $f(a)$ is the permutation of $1,2,\dots,q-1$ induced by multiplication by $p$ and reduction mod $q$. The maximum over all permutations $f$ (not just those arising from multiplication) of $\sum af(a)$ is attained when $f(a)=a$ for all $a$, and this corresponds to multiplication by 1; the minimum, when $f$ applied to $1,2,\dots,q-1$ gives $q-1,\dots,2,1$, and this corresponds to multiplication by $q-1$. 

Comment: Is there a known bound in terms of $s(1,q)$? I'm interested in a bound of the type $|s(a,q)| < c\cdot s(1,q)$, for some constant $c$ and any $1<a<q-1$.

Comment: @jiyanez, $c=1$ will do, of course. I think for fixed $q$ large enough and $1<a<q-1$ the maximum value of $|s(a,q)|$ is $s(2,q)$, which is not hard to evaluate.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, silly question. I wanted to say $c\cdot |s(a,q)| < s(1,q)$.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether you put $c$ on the left side or the right, does it? If $c=17$ works on one side, then $c=1/17$ works on the other, right?

Comment: Again correct. My main question is to know some estimation on how much bigger is s(1,q) than |s(a,q)|. So I wanted to know if there is a constant $c>1$ such that $c\cdot |s(a,q)| < s(1,q)$ for $1<a<q-1$. If not, any other inequality that gives an upper bound for |s(a,q)| that involves $s(1,q)$ would be useful.

Comment: @jiy, as I wrote a few comments up, try to prove that the second biggest value of $s(a,q)$ is $s(2,q)$, and then evaluate that.

Comment: The updated link for the Matthias Beck, Sinai Robins and Shelemyahu Zacks paper _Higher-dimensional Dedekind sums and their bounds arising from the discrete diagonal of the n-cube_ (linked in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63830/on-lower-upper-bounds-for-dedekind-sum/63866#comment160761_63866)) is https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305421

Answer (score 1):

See

http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/math/38267/upper-bounds-on-Dedekind-sums

(most of the relevant stuff is due to our own @Gerry Myerson)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any bound there, only some discussion on properties of the function. I'm completely ignorant in NT, I didn't mean some recent state of art result. There certainly must be some classical rough bound...

Comment: The link seems to be kaput. kb, that's Kevin Brown, now uses http://www.mathpages.com/home/ but I couldn't find the Dedekind sums essay there.

Comment: I found a sci.math thread titled "upper bounds on Dedekind sums" at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sci.math/dedekind$20AND$20Myerson/sci.math/_6-wYjghbKs/T4xbKG8JKpcJ and maybe the kb essay is drawn from it.

Comment: That link isn't working for me, but the thread can be accessed by going to https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math and then searching for "upper bounds on Dedekind sums" (with the quote marks).